Paths and retractions
There is this very simple question I came across, but I am having some difficulty with it. If someone could help me out, that would be great!
Question: Suppose $X$ is a deformation retract of $Y$ . Show that if $X$ is path-connected, then so is $Y$.
What I tried: So I took two points $y_0, y_1 \in Y$ (not in $X$), then I know there always exist a path from $r(y_0)$ to $r(y_1)$ (or $H(y_0, 1) to H(y_1, 1)$). I have an intuition that the homotopy $H$ (sometimes called the deformation retract) would allow me to create a path from $y_0$ to $r(y_0)$ and $r(y_1)$ to $y_1$.
If I am correct, could someone please explain how to construct that path?

@SassatelliGiulio  In the question, the retraction is $Y\to X$, not $X\to Y$.

You should correct the typos in your post. A suggestion is to prove that homotopy-equivalence preserves path-connectivity.
